# I feel like talking with you until you feel better

Tags: gerunds

I feel like talking with you until you feel better. So my question is that is "until you feel better" in a correct tense? especially when the main clause is "talking with you". Maybe I should say I feel like talking with you until you feeling better.

Comment: No, you shouldn't, although you could say "...until you _are_ feeling better".

Comment: thank you , so the main clause here is "feel like talking" or "taking"?

Comment: Your first sentence "I feel like talking with you until you feel better" is perfectly correct grammatically. Using "until you feeling better" would be incorrect, though as pointed out by Kate "until you are feeling better" would work.